# How can I programatically passcode lock my iphone?

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak, password-protection, iphone-privateapi

Is it possible to programatically password lock an iPhone?

My iphone is jailbroken , i can use private Apis & the app is not for app store.

I don't want answers just bluntly saying "Apple does not allow that". I know there would be no official way of doing it, and certainly not for an App Store application.

Comment: Which version of iOS?

Comment: can you please tell what is the status  of it